# How should I translate 株式会社 into English?

Tags: translation

This is a question that has been very challenging for me.

Why? Well, the Wikipedia article on [kabushiki gaisha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabushiki_gaisha) should explain why.

Seriously, the article gives multiple translations, which may or may not be accurate.

I would greatly appreciate some insight on this matter.

Comment: If you're looking for the translation of a specific company, most large Japanese companies have their official English names. Look at 会社概要 or similar section of their website.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! That should help me figure out the appropriate translation the next time I read up on a Japanese company!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to translate anything depends on the context.

- Sometimes this is rendered simply as *`[Company Name]`**, Inc.***
- Another option is *`[Company Name]` **Corporation***
- Yet another option is *`[Company Name]` **Co., Ltd.***
- If the Japanese-ness is important, *`[Company Name]`**, KK***
- In isolation, it really depends on what you're trying to convey.  If you're trying to talk about the specifics of this kind of joint-stock company in the context of the Japanese financial and legal system, you'd probably start by saying *"we're talking about Japanese joint-stock companies, commonly called* kabushiki gaisha *in Japanese; for convenience, we will use this term below..."*

What is the objective of your use of this term?  Figure that out first, and how to translate it (if at all) will become clearer.